# How to merge single Column matrix in MATLAB having variable length on each iteration of for loop with all its previous values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working in MATLAB and I have a row (or column) Matrix calculated on each iteration of for loop.
Suppose on first iteration of for loop

```
 A=[1 2 5 7]
```

On second iteration of for loop

```
 A=[2 5  1  8  4 5]
```

The length of A is variable. I want the result as follows.

```
B=[1 2 5 7 2 5 1 8 4 5]
```

i.e. B should have the results of all the previous iterations in single row or column matrix.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: B = [ ]; for... B = [B, A]; ... end

Comment: Thank you. My problem solved.

Comment: in theory if you have a vague idea how large array B will be, it's going to be much faster if you preallocate. Even if you're not sure, worst case scenario is that you'll have to 'snip' a bunch of zeros after you're done.